# Get the last statement execution date on an MSSQL Database

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, log

In an MSSQL Database, I am trying to know when was the last statement executed for that database.

So, is there any log that I can use to see the required activity records (could be the Transaction Log, but I am not sure how to get dates from it)?

Comment: The transaction log does not store select statements. Also if you have a query like select from db1.dbo.table1 join db2.dbo.table2, which database do you think you’ll find in the query plan attribute?

Answer (score 3):

You will want to use the [`sys.dm_exec_query_stats`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-query-stats-transact-sql) dmv. If you simply want to see the last statement that was executed, this should get you started (note: you need to execute this in the context of your database e.g. by using the `USE <db_name>` command):

```
SELECT
deqs.creation_time
,   deqs.last_execution_time
,   dest.text
,   SUBSTRING(dest.text, 
        (deqs.statement_start_offset/2) + 1,
            ((CASE statement_end_offset 
                WHEN -1 
                    THEN DATALENGTH(dest.text)
                ELSE deqs.statement_end_offset
                END 
                    - (deqs.statement_start_offset/2) + 1)))
AS statement_text
, deqp.query_plan
FROM 
sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY 
sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
CROSS APPLY 
sys.dm_exec_query_plan(deqs.plan_handle) AS deqp
WHERE deqs.last_execution_time = (SELECT MAX(last_execution_time)
                                FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats)
```

Comment: On a 2008 instance, the query works but shows all statements for all DBs even when selecting one beforehand. However, joining with the dm_exec_plan_attributes and checking the dbid attribute can specify the DB.

Answer (score 1):

You can try these 2 queries

```
SELECT deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], dest.TEXT AS [Query], dest.dbid
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

or

```
SELECT conn.session_id, sson.host_name, sson.login_name, 
 sqltxt.text, sson.login_time,  sson.status, sson.database_id
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections conn
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions sson 
ON conn.session_id = sson.session_id
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(most_recent_sql_handle) AS sqltxt
ORDER BY conn.session_id
```

Comment: Thanks. The fırst query worked, the second didn't. However, the first query seems to be giving me results for all the DBs in the server, not just the selected one.

Answer (score 1):

The query provided in [DimUser's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/198442) only needed an extra join with [`sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-plan-attributes-transact-sql) to be able to get to the required DB records only:

```
SELECT
deqs.creation_time
,   deqs.last_execution_time
,   dest.text
,   SUBSTRING(dest.text, 
        (deqs.statement_start_offset/2) + 1,
            ((CASE statement_end_offset 
                WHEN -1 
                    THEN DATALENGTH(dest.text)
                ELSE deqs.statement_end_offset
                END 
                    - (deqs.statement_start_offset/2) + 1)))
AS statement_text
, deqp.query_plan
FROM 
sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY 
sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
CROSS APPLY 
sys.dm_exec_query_plan(deqs.plan_handle) AS deqp
CROSS APPLY 
sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes(deqs.plan_handle) AS pa
WHERE deqs.last_execution_time = (SELECT MAX(last_execution_time)
                                FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats)
AND pa.attribute = 'dbid' AND pa.value = DB_ID()
```